# cannot found Password argument when reset mailbox password using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using powershell command to reset password for an existing mailbox, however, it comes out an error message says "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Password'." It's weird, because the 'Password' is a parameter according to MSDN http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981.aspx. Did I miss something?
My code:

```
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        try
        {
            remoteRunspace.Open();

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
            ps.AddCommand("Set-Mailbox");
            string PrincipalName = userId + emailDomain;
            ps.AddParameter("Identity", identity);
            ps.AddParameter("UserPrincipalName", PrincipalName);
            ps.AddParameter("Name", name);
            ps.AddParameter("DisplayName", name);
            ps.AddParameter("Password", emailPwd);//emailPwd is defined as securestring and set value previously, so it cannot be the exception reason
            ps.Invoke();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            remoteRunspace.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

This parameter **applies to objects in the cloud-based service. It isn’t available for on-premises deployments.**

This parameter is available for **multi-tenant deployments. It isn't available for on-premises deployments.** For more information about multi-tenant deployments, see Multi-Tenant Support.

The Password parameter resets the password of the user account associated with the cloud-based mailbox.

Comment: Then how to reset the password?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using on-premise Exchange, then setting the password is an AD account management function.  Depending on your domain level, you can use ADSI, the AD module from the RSAT tools, or the Quest AD cmdlets.